# Python code to generate sha1 checksum of numbers between 0 and 10

Tags: python, sha1, hashlib

I'm trying to write a python code to generate sha1 checksum of numbers between 0 and 10
here is my code:

```
import hashlib 

for i in range (10):
    num = str(i)
    result = hashlib.sha1(num.encode()) 
    print(result.hexdigest())
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 

      4 for i in range (10):
----> 5     num = str(i)
      6     result = hashlib.sha1(num.encode())
      7     print(result.hexdigest())

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. It works just fine. It seems you don't post you whole code. are you assign something to `str` in your code somewhere ? like this: `str = 2`

Comment: Do you run it in an interactive shell? Is it possible you've used a variable named `str` and overwritten the builtin str?

Comment: @lolopop I run it in jupyter notebook, looks like I have used a variable named str before. fixed by opening another jupyter notebook.

Comment: Great to hear! In the future, try `print(str)` on similar errors if you're not sure about what you did. Restarting the notebook will also reset the builtins and solve it.